# Pain without consciousness

Tags: pain

I know about blindsight, so I'm wondering if there are cases of people in pain who demonstrate all the behaviours of pain (e.g. putting hand in cold water after getting burnt, whining about the pain), but don't feel the pain. Also are there cases of deafhearing?

Comment: Yes, there is deafhearing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deaf_hearing.  The normal reaction to getting burnt, called the [withdrawal reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Withdrawal_reflex), is an example of reacting to pain without feeling it (the feeling of pain comes after the behavior has already been executed).

Comment: It depends how you [define pain](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK99533/), actually.